# Same OpenID code working on 1 server not working on another

Tags: php, openid

We implemented OpenID for Google Marketplace on this online hosting and it worked perfectly fine. But its not working on another server which DOES NOT have cPanel unlike the online hosting. Its failing authentication with this message: "Nonce already used or out of range"

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

look if the date of the server is correct, if its in the future you get this error.